# Enable [save & save as] only If there is an open file

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010, menustrip

I have MDI form Application, This application contains a menuStrip.
The menuStrip contains `Save` & `save as`.

What I want is, if there is an open file(**MDI child**) the `save` & `save as` will be enable, otherwise disable.
**Note:** I haven't any code to do that because I don't know where can I write the code.

Now, `How I can write the code?` and `where ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on create child window,

```
 var newChild = new Form() { MdiParent = this };
 menuItem.Enabled = true;
 newChild.FormClosing += (s, o) => menuItem.Enabled = (this.MdiChildren.Length  == 1) ? false : true;
 newChild.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can I get `close` child window? Note: the `Mdi children` are created dynamically.

Comment: What's the meaning of this `(s, o) =>`?

Comment: its a [lamda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx). when the created form closes, the (anonymous) method fired.